# Django UserPassesTestMixin raises an unhandled exception

Tags: python, django, exception, django-views, django-extensions

I'm using the `UserPassesTestMixin` on one of my views. It works fine, but every time a user fails the test (`test_func` returns False), an exception is raised in the server:

```
Forbidden (Permission denied): /m/chats/8/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  .../django/contrib/auth/mixins.py", line 48, in handle_no_permission
    raise PermissionDenied(self.get_permission_denied_message())
django.core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: Sorry, you can't access this chat.
[11/Apr/2022 11:53:04] "GET /m/chats/8/ HTTP/1.1" 403 135
```

Why doesn't it just show the last line? Like a 404 error when using a `get_object_or_404` function. And also, it only uses the `permission_denied_message` attribute that I set for the exception message and it is not shown to the user.

I know that I can override the `handle_no_permission` method, but is there a better way? Why does this even happen? `get_object_or_404` raises an exception too; so how come that one is handled and this one is not??

Comment: Django raises an error such that the view handles it properly and renders the page. It simply shows the traceback. But the error is part of the flow logic.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem So I have to catch it? and why there is no traceback for `Http404`? in the end, they are both raised in the `dispatch` method.

Comment: no it is catched by the Django system, and will eventuall return a 403 HTTP response.